# llvm pass ubuntu repository installation

Tags: ubuntu, llvm

I installed llvm and clang on ubuntu 14.04 from the repository as instructed on http://llvm.org/apt/. Now i need to write a llvm pass.

I am following the guide as on http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html. In the "setting the build environment", it says to write a makefile and include `makefile.common`.

I searched for this file, but i cannot find it.

Can someone correctly point out the procedure that allows me write the llvm pass?

Comment: Casual browsing unearthed http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/Makefile.common?revision=169569&view=markup

Comment: I found this folder /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/build that contains Makefile.common . The file that the makefile given on  http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html mentions says to include makefile.common . So, I changed the LEVEL parameter to /usr/lib/llvm-3.5/build .. and typed in make in terminal. I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official LLVM tutorials expect you to use a from-source build of LLVM, developing a pass within it. So you'll need to do a SVN checkout of LLVM and build it, this is pretty easy on a modern Ubuntu - see http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html. On 14.04 the gcc version is new enough to build latest LLVM, so you don't need a custom toolchain.

Alternatively. you can take a look at the https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples project: it has up-to-date samples of building tools and custom passes with LLVM *out of the source tree*. All you need for that is a binary build of LLVM (with access to headers and built objects), such as one you can download from the LLVM downloads website, you don't need to built it yourself.

Comment: I built llvm , clang and compiler-rt from the source as provided in the getting started document and its working perfectly. Thanks for the help!